# Different buttons should do different function

Tags: javascript, html, jsp

The problem is, I have to create a monthly attendance displaying webpage. In the table, the records are : date and status (Attended,Permission,On duty etc.). The 'status' is a button, and on clicking it, I should get a dialog box which states the reason. (eg. For status - permission, the reason can be 'not well', for on duty, it can be 'advertisement campaign etc.'). The exact status and reason is in the database, and I have taken it from the database and stored in an array.

```
 out.println("         <tr>\n" +
                "            <td style = \"text-align:center\" height=\"40\"><font style=\"color: black\">"+ db.date[i] +"</font> </td>\n" +
                "            <td style = \"text-align:center\" height=\"40\"> <font style=\"color: "+colour+"\">" + "<button onclick=\"document.getElementById('id01').style.display='block'\" style=\"width:auto; -webkit-box-align: center; \"> " +db.status[i]+ " </button>  </a>" +"</font> </td>\n" +
                "         </tr>   ");
        reason = db.reason[i];
    }
```

'id01' is a box and it should display the info. The point is, `date[i]`, `status[i]` and `reason[i]` have the corresponding values. The ith box should hold `date[i]`, `status[i]`. On clicking `status[i]`, a pop-up box should open which should display `reason[i]`.

Everything is ready, but for the `reason[i]` part. In the attempts I've made, `reason[0]` shows up for all buttons.

Please explain a way to remedy this.

Comment: Can you share some code snippet as well?

Answer (score 0):

use a for loop for displaying the data. something like this should work

```
<table>
<tr>
    <th>Date</th>
    <th>Reason</th>
    <th>Status</th>
</tr>
<tr>
    <%
        for(int i=0;i<length_of_array;i++)
        {

    %>
    <td><%=date[i]%></td>
    <td><button onclick="alert('Reason is<%=reason[i]%>')">Click here to get Reason</button></td>
    <td><%=status[i]%></td>
    <%
        }
    %>
</tr>
</table>
```

Check the data from your database if it is still showing for zero. If still not working share your code.

Comment: This would work, but I'm looking for is that the 'status' be a button, on clicking which the reason would show up.

Comment: I think this is what you meant. I have edited the post